# Rust-Rocket cannot be compiled

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I have set up a rust base project according to the Getting Started page of the rocket-framework:

1. I added this line to my Cargo.toml: `rocket = "0.4.10"`
2. My main.rs:

   ```
   #![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

   #[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

   #[get("/")]
   fn index() -> &'static str {
       "Hello, world!"
   }

   fn main() {
       rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
   }
   ```

When I try to run (or `cargo build` it) I get the following error:

```
   Compiling rocket v0.4.10 error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn handler::Handler + 'static): handler::Handler` is not satisfied    --> /Users/.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rocket-0.4.10/src/rocket.rs:299:41
    | 299 |             let outcome = route.handler.handle(request, data);
    |                                         ^^^^^^ the trait `handler::Handler` is not implemented for `(dyn handler::Handler + 'static)`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`. error: could not compile `rocket` due to previous error
```

I also tried it with previous versions of the rocket framework, all of them threw the same error.

Of course I'm using the latest nightly version of rust, right before `cargo build` I entered following commands:

```
rustup override set nightly
info: using existing install for 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'
info: override toolchain for '/Users/...' set to 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'

  nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.58.0-nightly (bd41e09da 2021-10-18)
```

Is there a known issue with the latest rust compiler on MacOS? Is there any other solution I could try?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Nightly. Try installing a slightly older version – `rustup install nightly-2021-10-07` worked for me.

Comment: Alternatively use stable toolchain and rocket 0.5 release candidate

Comment: Reverting to a previous nightly-version actually did work and solved this problem.

Comment: Here's the corresponding bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/89935 This should be fixed in tomorrow's nightly release.